# JDBC + ng-grid(AngularJS 1.4+) Pagination Oracle 11(Millions of records)

Tags: angularjs, spring, jdbc, oracle11g

Want to know the best way/approach to stream millions of records from DB table(oracle 11)

I tried simple

1. stmt.executeQuery() with setFetchSize on stmt, resultset etc. but it did not return any records when table has millions of records
2. tried with oracle 'rownum' clause, still returns nothing no execption
3. There are procedures like below
   http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql-to-oracle/copy_export_csv_from_procedure

but it needs file package...

**My question is there any best approach to stream such millions of records to UI from backend???**

like best way to store large(how much) in local storage at browser? this has to secure storage as the **data is sensitive**?

Please help me with this.

**NOTE: ORM/JPA cannot be used as the table generation is dynamic**

Thanks!

Comment: no idea why someone down voted... ??? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is how I have solved it...

**step 1 :** oracle stored procedure to get the number of 'pages' based on your desired no. of records/page

```
create or replace
procedure sp_dynlkp_pages (pTable in varchar2, rowCnt out number)
  as

begin
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from ' || pTable into rowCnt;    
end;
```

**step 2 :** display the page numbers is drop down and on selection of page number from down fire rest call with input page number

```
create or replace procedure sp_dynlkp_data_view (pTable in varchar2, pageNumber in number, pageSize in number, p_data_cursor out sys_refcursor) 
as
  v_sql varchar2(4000);
  v_sql1 varchar2(4000);  

begin
  v_sql := '';
  for r in (select column_name from user_tab_cols where table_name = pTable)loop
    -- decrypt fn
    --v_sql := v_sql || 'f_decrypt(' || r.column_name ||', ' || dKey || ')' || ',';
    v_sql := v_sql || r.column_name || ',';
  end loop;
  v_sql := rtrim(v_sql, ',');-- || ' from ' || pTable; --|| ' where rownum < ' || r_cnt;

  v_sql1 := 'SELECT ' || v_sql || ' FROM
  (
      SELECT a.*, rownum r__
      FROM
      ( select * from '
         ||   pTable 
      || ') a
      WHERE rownum < ' || ((pageNumber * pageSize) + 1) 
  || ')
  WHERE r__ >= ' || (((pageNumber-1) * pageSize) + 1);
  --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql1);
  open p_data_cursor for v_sql1;         
end;
```

**NOTE:** On UI front I am using ng-grid(because of project spec), you guys can use any latest feature rich UI grid component.